# How to resize an image in pygame to reach the top/bottom of screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm remaking flappy bird in pygame but with a Star Wars theme. I've completed the art and general formatting of the game, but now I need to tweak the specifics. I've been switching numbers around to try to get the lightsabers to fully reach the top and bottom of the screen because at the moment there are sometimes gaps that aren't the intended space to pass through. 
[image]

```
import pygame
from random import randint
from pygame.locals import *

#Define Colors - RGB
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)

pygame.init()

#Screen Size
size = 700,500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy Bird in Python")

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def ball(x,y):
    #Radius of 20 px
    ballImg1 = pygame.image.load('PlayerFrame1.png')
    ballImg1 = pygame.transform.scale(ballImg1,(50,50))
    screen.blit(ballImg1, (x,y))
    ballImg2 = pygame.image.load('PlayerFrame2.png')
    ballImg2 = pygame.transform.scale(ballImg2,(50,50))
    screen.blit(ballImg2, (x,y))

def gameover():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,55)
    text = font.render("Game Over! Try Again?",True,red)
    screen.blit(text, [150,250])

def obstacle(xloc,yloc,xsize,ysize):
    pipe = pygame.image.load('blade.png')
    pipe1 = pygame.transform.scale(pipe,(xsize,ysize))
    pipe2 = pygame.transform.scale(pipe,(xsize,500))
    screen.blit(pipe1,[xloc,yloc,xsize,ysize])
    screen.blit(pipe2,[xloc,int(yloc+ysize+space),xsize,ysize+500]))

#If the ball is between 2 points on the screen, increment score
def Score(score):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,55)
    text = font.render("Score: "+str(score),True,white)
    screen.blit(text, [0,0])

x = 350
y = 250
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
ground = 477
xloc = 700
yloc = 0
xsize = 70
ysize = randint(0,350)
#Size of space between 2 blocks
space = 150
obspeed = 2
score = 0


while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed = -5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed = 4


    screen.fill(black)
    obstacle(xloc,yloc,xsize,ysize)
    ball(x,y)
    Score(score)

    y += y_speed
    xloc -= obspeed

    if y > ground:
        gameover()
        y_speed = 0
        obspeed = 0

    if x+20 > xloc and y-20 < ysize and x-15 < xsize+xloc:
        gameover()
        y_speed = 0
        obspeed = 0

    if x+20 > xloc and y+20 < ysize and x-15 < xsize+xloc:
        gameover()
        y_speed = 0
        obspeed = 0

    if xloc < -80:
        xloc = 700
        ysize = randint(0,350)

    if x > xloc and x < xloc+3:
        score = score + 1

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried using really-long images for this (as long as the screen is high) and just placing them such that the "trailing-edge" goes off-screen ?  Obviously the images at the top of the screen need to be placed by the bottom-edge poisiton of the bitmap rather than the top co-ordinate.

Comment: `PyGame` has `pygame.Rect()` to keep object's position and size and you can use it to blit image `blit(image, rect)`. And it has properties like `rect.x` `rect.y` but also `rect.bottom` which can use with `rect.bottom = screen.get_rect().bottom` to put object at the bottom of screen.

Comment: BTW: you should load and rescale images only once - now you load and scale it 60 times in one second.

Comment: if you wnat to rescale top and bottom pipe then you should use scale two times to create two parts with different height. If first uses `ysize` then second should use `screen_height - ysize - gap_size`

Comment: at the beginning you could create image with the same height as screen height and then you don't have to resize it later but only put it in correct place.

Comment: I just got it to work... I added the pipes as 2 seperate objects... except now the user can pass the ball through the bottom saber without losing the game? The bottom saber seems to no longer have a hitbox?

Comment: See the updated code above^

Comment: you have two pipes so you need two hitboxes. Better use `pygame.Rect()` to keep size because it has also `rect.colliderect()` and `rect.coolidepoint()` and you don't have to check collision on your own. ie, `if pipe1_rect.colliderect(ball_rect) or pipe2_rect.colliderect(ball_rect): gameover()`

Comment: see documentation for [pygame.Rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

Comment: Do you have any idea how to implement it using the current code (ie all the if statements). I'm working on this with a friend and that's his portion, I don't want to change it too much...

Comment: use `pygame.Rect()`  and you will need only `if pipe1_rect.colliderect(ball_rect) or pipe2_rect.colliderect(ball_rect): gameover()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load image only once and rescale to window height - and get its size and position as `pygame.Rect()` (using `get_rect())`

```
image = pygame.image.load("images.png").convert()
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (50, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
image_rect = image.get_rect()
```

and then you can create `pygame.Rect()` for every pipe

```
pipe1_rect = image_rect.copy()
pipe2_rect = image_rect.copy()
```

If gap has size 200 and it should be 300 pixel at top

```
gap_size = 200
gap_top = 300
```

then positions of pipes will be

```
pipe1_rect.bottom = gap_top
pipe2_rect.top = pipe1_rect.bottom + gap_size
```

and you will blit it as

```
screen.blit(image, pipe1_rect)
screen.blit(image, pipe2_rect)
```

and you will move it from right to left

```
pipe1_rect.x -= 1
pipe2_rect.x -= 1
```

---

Example code

**EDIT:** I added: gap is in random position, pipes are moving, when ball touch pipes then it prints "Game Over" in console/terminal, when pipes touch left side of screen then it prints "WIN" in console/terminal

```
import pygame
import random 

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 60

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

# empty 

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

image = pygame.image.load("Obrazy/images/paddle.png").convert()
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (50, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
image_rect = image.get_rect()

pipe1_rect = image_rect.copy()
pipe2_rect = image_rect.copy()

pipe1_rect.right = screen_rect.right # move to right of screen
pipe2_rect.right = screen_rect.right # move to right of screen

gap_size = 200
gap_top = 300

#pipe1_rect.bottom = gap_top
pipe1_rect.bottom = random.randint(50, SCREEN_HEIGHT-gap_size-50)
pipe2_rect.top = pipe1_rect.bottom + gap_size

ball_rect = pygame.Rect((0,0,100,100))
ball_rect.center = screen_rect.center

ball_speed = 5

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    # --- events ---
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ball_speed = -3

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ball_speed = 4

    # --- changes/moves/updates ---

    ball_rect.y += ball_speed

    pipe1_rect.x -= 1
    pipe2_rect.x -= 1

    if pipe1_rect.colliderect(ball_rect) or pipe2_rect.colliderect(ball_rect):
        print('Game Over')
        pipe1_rect.right = screen_rect.right
        pipe2_rect.right = screen_rect.right
        pipe1_rect.bottom = random.randint(50, SCREEN_HEIGHT-gap_size-50)
        pipe2_rect.top = pipe1_rect.bottom + gap_size

    if pipe1_rect.left == 0:
        print("WIN")
        pipe1_rect.right = screen_rect.right
        pipe2_rect.right = screen_rect.right
        pipe1_rect.bottom = random.randint(50, SCREEN_HEIGHT-gap_size-50)
        pipe2_rect.top = pipe1_rect.bottom + gap_size

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    screen.blit(image, pipe1_rect)
    screen.blit(image, pipe2_rect)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, ball_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- FPS ---

    ms = clock.tick(FPS)
    #pygame.display.set_caption('{}ms'.format(ms)) # 40ms for 25FPS, 16ms for 60FPS
    fps = clock.get_fps()
    pygame.display.set_caption('FPS: {}'.format(fps))

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful... you were very right about rect() being useful. The only thing is that now I don't know how to implement the ball movement?

Comment: use `pygame.Rect()` to keep ball position - `ball_rect`. When you press key then change speed and later in part `changes/moves/updates"` add this speed to `ball_rect.y`

Comment: is it just basically adding the code from my old version to that section?

Comment: I added this to my example. But I had to use lower values for speed.

Comment: I want to thank you SO much! It finally works exactly how I had imagined it... its so fun to see a project work out. Thanks again!

Comment: next step: keep pipes on list to have more pipes and to use `for`-loops to move and draw them.

Comment: as one final question, how would you add another rect() that was essentially invisible but ran along the bottom of the screen, because the user can basically go under the pipes still

Comment: you can create `pygame.Rect()` and check its collision with ball but  you don't have to draw it. OR use `screen_rect.contains(ball_rect)` to check if ball didn't left screen. Doc: [pygame.Rect.contain](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.contains)